# Custom options added to Standard Value Set picklist are not included into managed package

Tags: managed-package, picklist, beta-managed-package, standard-field

We've added couple of new picklist options to standard picklist field Account.Type. In package.xml the following chunk of configuration is in place:

```
<types>
    <members>AccountType</members>
    <members>LeadSource</members>
    <name>StandardValueSet</name>
</types>
```

When we are deploying codes between sandboxes, new picklist values are migrated as well. The problem appears when we try to package our creation as managed package. There is no explicit options to include standard value sets (as I get they should be included automatically when we add Account.Type field through dependency detection mechanism). Relying on auto-detection, those new picklist options were not included into managed package at all, despite that they are used in some account's record types (explicit dependency).

Are we doing something wrong? Is there alternative approach how to include them? Is it possible at all to package custom values for standard value set?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, you can't package any standard fields, including standard value sets. Only [this list of components](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_packageable_components.htm) is available for packaging.

Comment: That list looks like not complete for me, for instance global value sets is not mentioned there, but they are allowed to be packaged (the closest to standard value set). Are there any workarounds? Or just - don't use standard picklist fields if you need to extend them and switch to custom one? I wish, I had known this from the beginning)

Answer (score 1):

Standard value sets are still not supported at the time of MD API version 45.

Latest support metrics for what can be and can't be packaged is here:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/metadata-coverage/